# The argument type 'Obx' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-getx

```
return DefaultTabController(
            length: filteredList.length,
            child: Scaffold(
              appBar: AppBar(
                backgroundColor: (Colors.white),
                iconTheme: const IconThemeData(color: Colors.black),
                title: Transform.translate(
                  offset: const Offset(-24.0, 0.0),
                  child: Image.asset("assets/images/logo.png",
                      fit: BoxFit.contain, height: 22),
                ),
                bottom: PreferredSize(
                  preferredSize: widget.tabbarenable
                      ? const Size.fromHeight(30.00)
                      : const Size.fromHeight(0.00),
                  child: ColoredBox(
                    color: Colors.white,
                    child: Column(
                      children: [
                        widget.tabbarenable
                            ? TabBar(
                                labelColor: Colors.purple[100],
                                indicatorColor: Colors.purple,
                                isScrollable: true,
                                labelPadding:
                                    const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 8.0),
                                tabs: tabs)
                            : Container()
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

I am deciding Tabbar enable or disable with boolen value: tabbarenable but this is not suitable for my solution because everytime I have to run whole page only disable to the Tabbar.

Now I decided to use GetX now but when I enter it: `Obx( () =>`  to bottom: PreferredSize I am getting this error `The argument type 'Obx' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'PreferredSizeWidget?'``

any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well `AppBar` **bottom** takes argument of type `PreferredSizeWidget` So you cannot assign Obx Directly with it. So you either have to use your own **custom app bar**, use `Obx` inside the widget or bellow code that is to create a custom widget that takes action for you by implementing `PreferredSizeWidget`. Note: this will still require you to give it a preferredSize for compulsion.

```
class BottomOfAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
  const BottomOfAppBar({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Obx(() => Container());
  }

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(55.0);
}
```